# Followed tutorial but searched for element returns none

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am watching tutorials online, and other people are able to do it, so curious why can't I?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
BaseURL = "https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/"


productlink = []


for x in range(1,6):     
    r = requests.get(f'https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/search?q=japanese+whiskey&pg={x}&psize=24&sort=rdesc')

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

    productlist = soup.find_all('li',class_='product-grid__item')

    for item in productlist:
        for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
            productlink.append(BaseURL + link['href'])


testlink = 'https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/p/47669/ichiros-malt-double-distilleries-465'

r2 = requests.get(testlink)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
time.sleep(5)
name = soup.find('h1', class_="product-main__name")

print(name)
rating = soup.find('span', class_="review-overview__rating star-rating star-rating--45")
print(rating)

price = soup.find('p', class_='product-action__price')
print(price)
```

Answer (score 2):

#### What happens?

There is a typo in your code you are referencing the `r` from your loop and not the `r2`, so you wont find your elements and result with `None`

#### How to fix?

Just change the following lines:

```
r2 = requests.get(testlink)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
```

to

```
r2 = requests.get(testlink)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r2.content, 'lxml')
```

#### Output

```
<h1 class="product-main__name">
Ichiro's Malt Double Distilleries
<span class="product-main__sub-name">(46.5%)</span>
</h1>
<span class="review-overview__rating star-rating star-rating--45">
<span>
4.5
</span>
</span>
<p class="product-action__price">£115</p>
```